# What is an ATB file?

Tags: vb6, infragistics

I'm trying to understand a legacy VB6 application. It seems that some of the GUI toolbars are defined by a binary file with the suffix "atb". I think (but I'm not 100% sure) that this file has been generated by an application called "Infragistics UltraToolBars 4". (I also think that "atb" is an abbreviation for "Active ToolBars".) I want to track down the "source code" for the .atb file. So do you know more details about how you create an .atb file and how it is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never used Infragistics controls myself but Google [suggests](http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/t/9069.aspx) that you [are right](http://news.archive.infragistics.com/readmessage?id=%3CXns940670456F03Dmscatconditionde@167.206.60.196%3E&group=infragistics.products.archived.com.general) and suggests that atb is a private binary format.

ComponentSource have a free [help file for Infragistics UltraSuite](http://www.componentsource.com/products/ultrasuite/downloads.html?rv=36638) including the ActiveToolBars Control - look in Igtbars3.hlp. It says ATB files are "Layout files are used to store information about the position of the Tools and ToolBars utilized by an ActiveToolBars control, and provide an efficient way for your application to maintain a user's Tool and ToolBar settings between sessions." There's sample code to save and load these files. For example `SSActiveToolBars1.SaveLayout App.Path & "/RTFEdit.Atb"`

Also, have you tried opening the project in the VB6 IDE and then looking at the properties of the GUI toolbars? There might be a "custom" option in the property window, that will open a special dialogue box that lets you change the GUI toolbar appearance.

Comment: Thanks a lot, MarkJ! Your answer helped me get unstuck, in particular your mention of the "custom" option (which I had overlooked).

Comment: @user181813 Glad it helped! Many complicated controls use that "custom" option to bring up really detailed dialogue boxes and special editing GUIs for the control properties. Always worth a look.